# How to plot a function $\psi(r,\theta,\phi=0)$ in polar coordinates?

Tags: plotting, coordinate-transformation

I have a function $\psi(r,\theta,\phi=\phi_0)$ with $\phi_0\in \Re$, $r\in[0,R]$ with $R\in \Re$, and $\theta \in [0,\pi]$ (spherical polar coordinates) and I want to plot it in Mathematica. I guess the proper way to do that is in polar coordinates, but how do I do that?

The function is:

$$\psi(r,\theta,\phi=0)=r^2e^{-r}\cos \theta  $$

Comment: Have you tried searching the docs? Lookup `PolarPlot`...

Comment: How about `ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[θ], r Sin[θ], r^2 Exp[-r] Cos[θ]}, {r,0,4}, {θ,0,π}]`.

Comment: @rm-rf Yeah, but PolarPlot needs $r$ as function of $\theta$.

Comment: What coordinate is supposed to represent $\psi$?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Actually $\psi$ is a wave function for the Hydrogen Atom.

Comment: I meant in the plot. Since the section $\phi = \hbox{constant}$ is a plane (technically, a half-plane since $r\ge0$), $\psi$ could be represented by a displacement perpendicular to the plane as in Suba's answer or RiemannZeta's comment. Is that what you're after?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I don't understand completely your question. Actually I put $\phi=0$ in the function just for keep in mind that the expression is in spherical coordinates, i.e. $\theta \in [0,\pi]$ is the polar angle. And I think the function $\psi$ could be thought as a function taking values in the $x$ axis and the $y-z$ plane could be thought as the polar plane with the difference that $\theta \in [0,\pi]$ and $\psi(-\theta)=\psi (\theta)$.

Comment: My question is more or less this: Is Suba Thomas's answer what you seek?

Answer (score 6):

First find the condition for $\phi=0$ in cartesian coordinates.

```
Last@CoordinateTransform["Cartesian" -> "Spherical", {x, y, z}];
Solve[% == 0, y]
```

> {{y -> 0}}

Convert the expression to cartesian coordinates, apply the condition, and plot.

```
TransformedField["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", 
r^2 Exp[-r] Cos[θ], {r, θ, ϕ} -> {x, y, z}] /. %;

Plot3D[%, {x, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, AxesLabel -> {x, z, ψ}]
```

[image]

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: First you set `y -> 0`, which I agree with.  But I do have a criticism/question: Next in `Plot3D` you plot the transformed expression (let `expr = %`) as if it were the graph of `y == expr`.  Why `y == expr` if `y` is `0`?

Comment: Michael E2, Hopefully this fig https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:3D_Spherical.svg will clear things. $\phi==0$ corresponds to $y==0$. $expr$ is a function of $x$ and $z$, and its values are plotted along the $y$ axis.

Comment: I know all that.  That means the $y$ on the $y$ axis is not the same $y$ that is zero when $\phi=0$.  That's confusing to me.  I think $\psi$ ought to be treated as an intensity (as in `DensityPlot`) or as you have done (but not labeled $y$).

Comment: I think you are taking issue with just the label? My thought flow is that there is one $y$ axis, the abscissae lie on $y==0$ and the ordinate can take values along the $y$ axis; and I also labeled it $y$. Now, I have changed it to $\psi$.

Comment: Yes, I had read it that the $y$'s were the same.  With relabeling the confusion disappears.  I don't think the OP's question is sufficiently clear yet, but this is a reasonable interpretation.  +1.

Comment: Since you pointed it out, it's becoming clearer to me why the earlier thing was an abuse of notation. Thanks. Let's see what the OP has to say.

Answer (score 2):

You could visualize with [`ColorFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html), e.g.:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := Exp[-{x, y, z}.{x, y, z}] {x, y, z}.{x, y, z} z
min = NMinimize[f[x, 0, z], {x, z}][[1]];
max = NMaximize[f[x, 0, z], {x, z}][[1]];
cf = Function[{x, y, z}, 
   ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[f[x, 0, z], {min, max}]]];
Legended[ParametricPlot3D[{r Sin[t], 0, r Cos[t]}, {r, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 
   2 Pi}, ColorFunction -> cf, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 50], 
 BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {min, max}}]]
```

[image]